# Cannot add Toolbar end of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitoolbar

I'm trying to add a Toolbar in interface builder in the following View:

[image]

However, when adding the toolbar, it is not going at the bottom of the screen but is like this:
[image]

As a result, at runtime, the toolbar is appearing like a row in the table.

Any suggestion why the toolbar is not going at the end of the screen and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are adding toolbar inside table view,

1. If you want to add it at **bottom**, please add it **outside** tableView.
2. If you want it **inside** table view you can use **viewForFooter** delegate.

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView` you can have only `cells`, that's why `toolbar` getting add as cell instead a `toolbar` in bottom. So for adding `toolbar` at that `controller`, you can decrease the size of tableView by **44 (size of a toolbar)** and than in `Controller's View` you can add your `toolBar` . I added a ScreenShot [image]

Comment: This is the issue, I'm not able to decrease the size of the tableview

Comment: why not @Noor, how you added tableView can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag a UIViewController into Storyboard
2. Drag a UIToolbar and place it bottom of the ViewController
3. Drag a UITableView on top of the ViewController

Declare delegate and data source like this.

```
   @interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Hope this will help you.